# Measure of an open set containing a Borel set of measure $1/3$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I met this problem preparing for my qual exam.

Given a Borel subset A of the unit unterval with Lebesgue measure 1/3, there exists an open set O containing A with measure 2/3.

Using the regularity of Borel set, it can easily be shown that there exists such open set with measure less than 2/3, but how can I get a set with measure exactly 2/3?

Also, does the number 2/3 here bear any significance?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $m((\Bbb R\setminus K)\cap[-t,t])$ is a continuous function of $t$.

Comment: What is K in your comment? Can you be more specific?

Comment: A compact subset of $A$

Comment: I still don't know why you said is true and how it would help.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to be posting a solution or even the actual start of an actual solution, was just trying to give a hint how something like "exactly $2/3$" might come about...

Comment: It's on the unit interval so just use $f(t) = m([0,t])$.

Comment: @Ramiro Do you have any hint for me on how to proceed?

Comment: I have posted a complete answer. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be open with $A\subset B$ and $m(B)<2/3$. Let $f(x)=m(B\cup (0,x))$.Then $f$ is continuous with $f(0)<2/3$ and $f(1)\ge 1.$

The only significance of the number $2/3$ is that it's more than $m(A).$

Comment: (+1) for such a nice and simple solution. Just to complement your solution: the answer to the OP follows from the intermediate value theorem. The continuity of $f$ follows from the identity $f(x)=m(B\cup (0,x))=m(B)+x-m(B\cap(0,x))$, and the fact that $x\mapsto m(B\cap(0,x))$ is continuous.

Comment: @JeanL. ... Or we can see that if $0\le y<x$ then $0\le f(x)-f(y)=m(\,(y,x)\setminus B)\le x-y$ so $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous on $[0,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

It is a little long for a comment.

Let $A \subseteq [0,1]$  be a Borel set such that $\mu(A)=1/3$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

In what follows, we will be considering the topology of $[0,1]$, so whenever we write "open" means open set in $[0,1]$.

Let $\Gamma = \{ B \subseteq [0,1]: B \text{ is open}, A\subseteq B, \mu(B) \leq 2/3\}$. Then:

1. Using the regularity of $\mu$ on Borel set, it is easy to see that $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$.
2. $\Gamma$ is partially ordered by $\subseteq$.
3. Given any totally ordered chain $\{B_\alpha\}$ in $\Gamma$, let $B= \bigcup_{\alpha} B_\alpha$, then $A \subseteq B \subseteq [0,1]$ and $B$ is open.
   Since, the topology of $[0,1]$ is second countable, we have that there is a countable famyly $\{D_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ of basic open set, such that $B = \bigcup_n D_n$ and, for all $k \in \Bbb N$, there is $\alpha$ such that $\bigcup_{n=0}^k D_n \subseteq B_\alpha$. So,  for all $k \in \Bbb N$, $\mu \left (\bigcup_{n=0}^k D_n \right ) \leq 2/3$. So, $\mu(B) = \mu \left (\bigcup_n D_n \right ) \leq 2/3$. So,  $B \in \Gamma$.

So, we can apply Zorn lemma to $\Gamma$. Let $E$ be a maximal element of $\Gamma$. Then $E \subseteq [0,1]$, $E$ is open, $A \subseteq E$ and $\mu(E) \leq 2/3$ and since $E$ is maximal, we can conclude  that $\mu(E)=2/3$.

In fact, if $\mu(E) < 2/3$, then  using the regularity of $\mu$ on Borel set and the fact that $\mu$ has no atoms, we would have an open set $F$ such that $E\subseteq  F \subseteq [0,1]$ and $\mu(E) < \mu(F)< 2/3$. Clearly $F \in \Gamma$ and contradicts the maximality of $E$.

So we have proved there is $E \subseteq [0,1]$, $E$ is open, $A \subseteq E$ and $\mu(E) = 2/3$.

**Remark**: In fact, this proof works for any second countable space $X$ with any outer regular measure $\mu$ defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. That means:

> Let $X$ be a second countable topological space and let $\mu$ be an outer regular atomless measure defined on the  Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. Then, given any Borel subset $A$ of $X$, and any $r \in (0,+\infty]$ such that $\mu(a) < r \leq \mu(X)$, there exists an open set $O$ containing A and having measure $r$.

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer is correct and it actually extends to a more general case.